# Submitting form to Ajax Post type

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have multiple Ajax calls (Get and Post) on a single page of Laravel Application, I want to post a form using AJAX Post but the form is using the first Ajax on the page which has the Get type. How can I make the form use the second Ajax with the Post type?

This is a snippet for the problem as the application is very large to show its code.

```
  $.ajax({  //First Ajax
          type: "GET",
          url: "/course/digital-marketing/facebook/fetch",       
          success: function (data) {

               function createOrUpdate(){
                document.getElementById("testForm").submit();// Form submission

                $.ajax({//Second Ajax
                    data: $('#testForm').serialize(),
                    url: "/course/digital-marketing/facebook",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log('Success:', data);
                        
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log('Error:', data);
                    }

                });

            }

              createOrUpdate()

          }
```

Comment: is there any response from the first ajax success?

Comment: I got an error; The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Comment: You need to add your route to the question, and both ajax url look the same. Try using route name.

Comment: You should probably add `event.preventDefault()` at the beginning of the JS function (before ajax method). Seems that link which is being clicked is acting as GET, but you need to prevent browser's default behavior in favor of using POST method over AJAX.